# Boundedness of solution to a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the nonlinear second order ode:
$u''(r)+mu'(r)/r + u(r)^p-u(r) =0, r\ge a>0$
where $m\ge 0$ and $p>1$ are constants.

In particular, this equation has a Lyapunov/Energy function
$
E(r)= \frac{u'(r)^2}{2}+\frac{u^{p+1}(r)}{p+1}-\frac{u^2(r)}{2},
$
from which we calculate that $E'(r) = -m\frac{u'(r)^2}{r}\le 0$, so energy is decreasing along trajectories, however, the paper I am reading claims that $E$ decreases to a finite constant as $r\to \infty$, why is the case that $E(r) \to -\infty$ excluded?

Comment: What happens for $u < 0$ if $p$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $p$ is an even positive integer, you certainly can have $E(r) \to -\infty$. Even worse, this can happen as $r$ approaches a finite value, rather than $\infty$.

EDIT:
Consider e.g. the case $p=2$, $m=0$.
  The Lyapunov function $u'^2/2 + u^3/3 - u^2/2$ is constant.  But many of the level curves of this in the $(u,u')$ plane are unbounded, and 
along them $u \to -\infty$ with $u' \to -\infty$.  And these will have
$|u'| \sim - (2/3)^{1/2} |u|^{3/2}$, which would make $u(t) \sim -6/(r - r_0)^2$ for some $r_0$.

Comment: That's what I am confused about, more specifically I am studying the initial value problem $u(a)=\alpha>0$ and $u'(a)=0$, if I consider only positive solutions, then $E(r)$ will be bounded from below and the asseration is true, but if the solution becomes negative I don't know...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think the paper only means positive solution, and only for positive solution we can claim they are bounded for $r\in (a,\infty)$